# Force Google Docs/Sheets to ALWAYS paste values only (merge formatting)

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs, keyboard-shortcuts, formatting, autohotkey

I do a LOT of copying from external sources and pasting into Google Docs/Sheets. Is this at all possible? I know the keyboard shortcut but can't seem to get used to it. Would save me so much time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Sheets & Google Docs does not allow to alter internal keyboard shortcuts so your options are:

- get used to official keyboard shortcut - <kbd>**`CTRL`**</kbd> + <kbd>**`SHIFT`**</kbd> + <kbd>**`V`**</kbd>
- remap your keyboard

---

To easily remap your keyboard shortcut you can use powerful **[AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/)** script:

```
IfWinActive, ahk_exe Chrome.exe
    {
        ^+V:: ;CTRL+SHIFT+V
        Send, {F2}
        return
    }
```

Above example takes the given keyboard shortcut and binds it to <kbd>**`F2`**</kbd> key.

---

Resources:

- **https://www.autohotkey.com/**
- **https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm**
- **https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinActive.htm**
- **https://www.pcmag.com/feature/362116/how-to-remap-your-keyboard/3**

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> doesn't work any more. Use **<kbd>Enter</kbd> > <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> > <kbd>Enter</kbd>** instead.

Comment: CTRL + SHIFT + V is working for me now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what works for me, I press the letter 'z' and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> is executed.

z::
Send, ^+v
return